# Manipulate a MenuItem’s enabled property at runtime

Tags: electron

I have an app that, in order, needs to:

1. Initialize its UI presence by creating a menu bar/notification tray icon with a menu.
2. Retrieve external data.
3. Based on the data retrieved, potentially enable a tray menu item that initialized in a disabled state.

In the docs, I don't see any obvious way of changing the enabled property of an existing menu item. Am I just not seeing it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up modifying the `enabled` value of the `MenuItem` itself:

```
myTrayMenu.items[atPosition].enabled = true;
```